# Least-squares fitting using completely monotonic functions

Tags: real-analysis, terminology, least-squares

I'm considering a function $f(x)$ defined over some range $[a,b]$ that is infinitely differentiable with the conditions that $f'(x)\geq 0$, $f''(x)\leq 0$, $f'''(x)\geq 0$, ..., i.e.,

$$(-1)^{n-1}f^{(n)}(x)\geq 0, \forall\,n\in\mathbb{N}^*, x\in[a,b].$$

For example, $f(x)=\ln x\,$ for $\,0<a<b\,$ satisfies the above conditions. An interesting property of the class $\,\mathcal{C}\,$ of such functions $\,f(x)\,$ that satisfy the above conditions is that if $\,f(x)\in\mathcal{C}\,$, so does $-f'(x)$. Is there a name for the class $\,\mathcal{C}\,$ of such functions? Also, if I'm fitting some noisy data points $\,(x_i,y_i)\,$ sampled on equal intervals of $\,\{x_i\}\,$ coordinates using least squares errors to a function $\,y=f(x)\in\mathcal{C}$, what is an efficient way to enforce the constraint $f(x)\in\mathcal{C}\,$?

Comment: I got interested in this question after reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotonic_regression. The function obtained by isotonic regression is not smooth (typically piecewise constant with jumps). So I'm thinking about using the function class $\,\mathcal{C}\,$ as a generalization.

Comment: $f'$ is a [completely monotonic function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompletelyMonotonicFunction.html)

Comment: @achillehui, cool, there's really a name for that. Thx!

Comment: Thanks to @achillehui for providing the terminology. The title is now updated for better search results.